# Find empty value for any name in file

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I have a file in the below format:

```
Name=Dan
Age=45
Name=Alex
Age=35
Cellphone=12345678901
Name=John
Age=
Cellphone=12345678901
```

This file has got 1000's of data items in above format, `Name=Value`.

If values are missing, and I want to find these in below output as 
missing value for Age.

I tried by using the cut command, `cut -d “=“ -f2 > some file`, then grep for an empty line, `grep -n ‘[[:blank:]]’ file`, then display the line number in the original file.

But since I have multiple files, this method looks complicated.

Is there any simpler method for this?

Comment: I did not understand what's the output you want for a single file. Could insert an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using this:

```
cat <filename> | sed "s/ /\n/g" | grep "=$"
```

This will replace your spaces to new lines (which will not work if you have values contaning spaces) and then look for entries with = followed by line end.

Comment: Since there are multiple files and the field name is always the same, it might be useful to use `cat -n`, which will display the line number.

Comment: This will also report _values_ that end in `=`, e.g. `key=value=`.

Answer (score 0):

If you treat your file as *delimited*, then you can match and output any lines whose second *field* consists of at most whitespace:

```
awk -F= '$2 ~ /^[ \t]*$/' file
```

Answer (score -1):

Using `grep` with extended regexp:

`grep -Eno "[A-Za-z]+=( |$)" /path/to/file`

Should print empty keys and corresponding line numbers.

Comment: Thanks , this is also helpful , above solution worked , thanks

Comment: This too would disallow values to end in `=`.